# How to make MySQL trigger on update in Table-A update all corresponding values in Table-B

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers

I have two tables Table1 : Rates Table2 : Books.
I want to make a trigger such that if rate of any currency changes all the rates in books table must change accordingly. Below is the structure of tables:

```
-----------------------------
| Table1 : Rate             |
-----------------------------
| id | name | rate | symbol |
-----------------------------
| 1  |Dollar|59.26 |  $     |
| 2  |Euro  |79.74 |  €     |
| 3  |Pound |98.61 |  £     |
-----------------------------


--------------------------------------
| Table2 : Books                     |
--------------------------------------
| id | name | Price | Cur | PriceInRs|
--------------------------------------
| 1  | ABC  | 15.00 |  $  | 889.43   |
| 2  | PQR  | 62.95 |  €  | 5019.63  |
| 3  | XYZ  | 49.99 |  £  | 4929.51  |
--------------------------------------
```

As the rate of any currency gets updated in Table1 : Rate. All the records of Column PriceInRs in Table2 : Books must reflect the changes in currency.

How should I create a MySQL Trigger?

Please Help

Comment: Question in the book table why do you store the currecy symbol instead of the id from the Rate Table ?

Comment: because the data in book table comes from excel file which has the structure like books table.

Comment: MySQL is not SQL SERVER

Comment: Personally, I'd create a view instead of a trigger - this calculation isn't that expensive, comparatively.  If you have too many rows you _might_ need to materialize the view, but there should be ways to query around that.  Note that your db structure being dictated by an Excel sheet is a bad idea; you can have it dictate a temp "import" structure, but not the actual design.  Especially because Excel uses floating-point for decimal numbers, which you **should not** be using for things like currency.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do , but I would strongly suggest to store the id from the rate table to the Books table instead of the symbol.

```
delimiter //
create trigger rate_update after update on Rate
for each row
begin
  if new.rate <> old.rate then
    update Books set PriceInRs = new.rate * Price where Cur = old.symbol ;
  end if ;
end ; //
delimiter ;
```

If you would have stored the id in the books table then the update query where clause would have been done using the id from the rate table and this is highly recommended.